# Uncommitted read SQL

Tags: db2

I have a question about uncommitted read. I understand that it is used for setting transaction isolation levels. But I am trying to understand a query which is as follows:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM customer_records as c, transaction_records as t 
    WHERE e.customer_id= t.customer_id 
union
    SELECT *
    FROM customer_records as c, transaction_records as t 
    WHERE e.customer_id= t.customer_id with ur;
```

As I understand it, this query is doing a union between already committed and uncommitted data for the records in both tables. Could someone elaborate on what would be the use of such data? And whether I am understanding the query correctly, as I think that `ur` is applied to second query only?

Comment: this looks to be IBM DB2, please remove the sql-server as tag from this question.

Comment: `with ur` is DB2 `with nolock` is sql server

Comment: refer this [link](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmstisol.htm) for more info on IBM Db2 isolation levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no second query this is one query with two select clauses and a union so the WITH UR applies to the whole query.

This query also does not make sense.  Since both selects are getting the same results and you are doing a union you will get the same results as the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_records as c, transaction_records as t 
WHERE e.customer_id= t.customer_id with ur;
```